# How to add global header parameter to all url paths in drf_spectacular?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, http-accept-language, drf-spectacular

I'm using drf_spectacular to be able to use swagger and it's working fine.
I define the required parameters for my API views (whether in the path or in the header) like this:

```
@extend_schema(
    OpenApiParameter(
            name='accept-language',
            type=str,
            location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER,
            description="fa or en. The default value is en"
    ),
)
```

but I don't want to add these lines of code to all of my API views. Is there an easy way to do this? (Something like defining these lines of code in SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS)

I already found an [APPEND_COMPONENTS](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#:%7E:text=%27APPEND_COMPONENTS%27%3A%20%7B%7D%2C) option in drf_spectacular's documentation but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: See a workaround [here](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/804)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom schema class from ***`drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema`*** and override the ***`get_override_parameters(...)`*** method as

```py
from drf_spectacular.openapi import AutoSchema

from drf_spectacular.utils import OpenApiParameter


class CustomAutoSchema(AutoSchema):
    global_params = [
        OpenApiParameter(
            name="accept-language",
            type=str,
            location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER,
            description="`fa` or `en`. The default value is en",
        )
    ]

    def get_override_parameters(self):
        params = super().get_override_parameters()
        return params + self.global_params
```

and then attach this **`CustomAutoSchema`** class in your **`DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS`** setting

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # YOUR SETTINGS
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "path.to.your.custom.class.CustomAutoSchema",
}
```